# how to copy columns from file 2 to file 1 when some columns matches between 2 files

Tags: text-processing, awk, bioinformatics

I have a file

```
head top_candidates
    25 elevation_e gene1 20 9 0.0246022994932004 5 8 10.9217937824527
    30 elevation_e gene1 59 18 0.0246022994932004 7 12 15.653559774527
    31 elevation_e gene3 34 10 0.0246022994932004 6 9 9.47018201139585
    108 elevation_e gene3 18 6 0.0246022994932004 4 7 6.86419248099239
```

and another file

```
head genes.bed
Chr00c0001  52974   70567   gene1
Chr00c0003  32983   33237   gene2
Chr00c0003  36241   36792   gene3
Chr00c0003  100286  101468  gene4
Chr00c0004  80876   93710   gene5
```

I want to paste columns 1,2 and 3 from the second file to the first file, when the column 4 of file 2 (gene1,2,..) matched with the column 3 of file 1.

My desired output:

```
head desired
25 elevation_e gene1 20 9 0.0246022994932004 5 8 10.9217937824527 Chr00c0001    52974   70567 
30 elevation_e gene1 59 18 0.0246022994932004 7 12 15.653559774527 Chr00c0001    52974   70567 
31 elevation_e gene3 34 10 0.0246022994932004 6 9 9.47018201139585 Chr00c0003    36241   36792
108 elevation_e gene3 18 6 0.0246022994932004 4 7 6.86419248099239 Chr00c0003    36241   36792
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
awk 'NR == FNR {T[$4] = $1 FS $2 FS $3; next} FNR == 1 {print "head desired"; next} {print $0, T[$3]}' file2 file1
head desired
    25 elevation_e gene1 20 9 0.0246022994932004 5 8 10.9217937824527 Chr00c0001 52974 70567
    30 elevation_e gene1 59 18 0.0246022994932004 7 12 15.653559774527 Chr00c0001 52974 70567
    31 elevation_e gene3 34 10 0.0246022994932004 6 9 9.47018201139585 Chr00c0003 36241 36792
    108 elevation_e gene3 18 6 0.0246022994932004 4 7 6.86419248099239 Chr00c0003 36241 36792
```